# Example of horizontal grid scrolling in material ui v5

Tags: material-ui, grid, horizontal-scrolling

In the previous version of material-ui v4.11.1 they had a Grid List component that in the current version was replaced by Image list. But in Gid List there was an example for Single line Grid list.

https://material-ui.com/components/grid-list/#single-line-grid-list

[image]

But in current version material ui v5.0.0-alpha.37

https://next.material-ui.com/components/image-list/

The example for horizontal scrolling is not provided for the Grid or Image List component.
And tried adding the modifications from the previous version.

```
flexWrap: "nowrap",
overflowX: "scroll",
```

but it doesn't work, I would appreciate if someone could share a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

So i ran into a similar issue and was able to solve this for version 5 of material UI. In your `ImageList` component, you want to define, within `sx`, an `overflow` of `auto`. Furthermore, the height at which you want your images to appear as on screen you will define with `rowHeight`, so I placed `rowHeight` at 200 for myself. Finally, within your `ImageListItem`, you want to set it, within `sx`, with a display of `flex` and a `flexDirection` of row, doing so allows each item to be placed horizontally. To add spacing in between each image, within the `img` tag define a `marginRight` of `1em` or whichever number you choose for your liking - remember this goes within your `style` attribute.

Here is my code example of creating a horizontal scroll of ImageList:

```
<ImageList sx={{ overflowX: 'auto' }} rowHeight={200}>
          <ImageListItem sx={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            {state.posts[i].images.map(image => {
              return (
              <img
              src={image}
              srcSet={image}
              alt='title'
              loading='lazy'
              style={{paddingRight: '1em'}}
              />
              )
            })}
          </ImageListItem>
        </ImageList>
```

Here are two images of what it looks like:

[image: First image]

[image: second image]

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69597992/how-to-implement-horizontal-scrolling-of-tiles-in-mui-gridlist