# How to implement horizontal scrolling of tiles in MUI GridList?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

This is my JS page where I need to implement the `GridList` component to show multiple tiles and is scrollable horizontally after list size crosses screen limits.

```
import React,{ useState} from "react";
import Header from "../../common/header/Header";
import "./Home.css";
import { GridList, GridListTile, GridListTileBar} from "@material-ui/core";

const images = [
    { thumbnail: { uri: 'https://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals',name:'animals'}},
    { thumbnail: { uri: 'https://lorempixel.com/200/200/city'  ,name:'city'}},
    { thumbnail: { uri: 'https://lorempixel.com/200/200/city'  ,name:'city'}},
    { thumbnail: { uri: 'https://lorempixel.com/200/200/city'  ,name:'city'}},
    { thumbnail: { uri: 'https://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature'  ,name:'nature'} },
    { thumbnail: { uri: 'https://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats'  ,name:'cats'} },
    { thumbnail: { uri: 'https://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats'  ,name:'cats'} },
    { thumbnail: { uri: 'https://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats'  ,name:'cats'} },
  ];

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header></Header>
      <header className="head">Upcoming Movies</header>
        <GridList cellHeight={180} cols={6}>
            {images.map((image) => (
            <GridListTile>
                <img src={image.thumbnail.uri} />
                <GridListTileBar
                    title={ image.thumbnail.name}
                />
            </GridListTile>
            ))}
        </GridList>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Note:** In the newer versions of MUI, [`GridList`](https://v4.mui.com/api/grid-list/#import)'s been changed to `ImageList`, the code below uses the latest API.

You can fill the column instead of row by using the code below:

```
<ImageList
  sx={{
    gridAutoFlow: "column",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fill,minmax(160px,1fr)) !important",
    gridAutoColumns: "minmax(160px, 1fr)"
  }}
>
  {images.map((image) => (
    <ImageListItem>
      <img src={image.thumbnail.uri} />
      <ImageListItemBar title={image.thumbnail.name} />
    </ImageListItem>
  ))}
</ImageList>
```

- `gridAutoFlow: 'column'`: Tell the grid to create another column if there is no space left instead of going to the next row.
- `gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(auto-fill, minmax(160px, 1fr))'`: Set the column min and max width, min is `160px`, if there is more than enough space (no need for horizontal scrollbar), set each column width equally.
- `gridAutoColumns: 'minmax(160px, 1fr)'`: Same as above but for the columns outside of the viewport.

### Live Demo

**V5**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**V4**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### References

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/